# Extracting and normalizing URLs in an HTML document

Tags: python, performance, strings, url, beautifulsoup

I have written code to get all urls on a webpage & put them in a set, and would like tips on simple changes I can make to increase its performance.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    url = link.get('href')
    if url is None or ' ' in url or '<' in url or '>' in url:
        continue
    if url.startswith('//'):
        url = url.replace('//', 'http://')
    if url.startswith('/'):
        url = hostname + url
    if '?' in url:
        url = url.split('?')[0]
    if '#' in url:
        url = url.split('#')[0]
    if url.endswith('/'):
        url = url[:-1]
    if url.endswith(excluded_extensions):
        continue
    if url.startswith(hostname):
        urls_set.add(url)
```

Comment: Because you don't want to use the urllib.parse module?

Comment: @sunny urllib.parse doesn't work for me because "urlparse recognizes a netloc only if it is properly introduced by ‘//’. Otherwise the input is presumed to be a relative URL and thus to start with a path component."

[link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Answer (score 3):

Some stuff you could perhaps do differently:

```
# your code
if url is None or ' ' in url or '<' in url or '>' in url:
    continue

# the alternative
if url is None or any(char in url for char in ' <>'):
    continue
```

Also, you can call the split method directly, without the `if` statement, as it will return a single item list with the full string inside if the character is not in the string:

```
# your code
if '?' in url:
    url = url.split('?')[0]
if '#' in url:
    url = url.split('#')[0]

# the alternative
for splitter in '?#':
    url = url.split(splitter, 1)[0]
```

Notice the micro-optimization of using the second argument of `split`, so that the string is only split at the first occurrence if there is more than one.

Answer (score 1):

`url.replace('//', 'http://')` is not quite right: it does a global replacement, but you intend to replace only the leading `//`.  You should write `url.replace('//', 'http://', 1)` instead.  Or better yet, `url = 'http:' + url`.